# How to generate a coupon code for a specific rule in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sales, coupon-codes

I need to **generate coupon code for a specific rule** after the order is placed. I am checking the sale-rule module. It will helped me if anyone know which class is actually I should use.

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I post my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works for me.

```
$code = $generator->generateCode();
$expirationDate = strtotime("+30 day");      

$coupon = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon');        
$coupon->setId(null)->setRuleId($ruleId)->setUsageLimit(1000)->setUsagePerCustomer(10000)->setExpirationDate($expirationDate)->setType(1)->setCode($code)->save();
```

Comment: Where does "$generator" come from?

Answer (score 2):

We need to know:

- `\Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponManagementInterface - \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Service\CouponManagementService` to generate coupon code.
- `\Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\CouponGenerationSpecInterface - \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Data\CouponGenerationSpec` to define a coupon code generator.

Remember to inject these classes in your constructor.

```
/** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Service\CouponManagementService $couponManagement **/

// Define a coupon code generator
// Get the rule in question
// Look at \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Data\CouponGenerationSpec $generator for options

$generator->setRuleId($ruleId)

if( !empty($parameters['format']) ){
  switch( strtolower($parameters['format']) ){
    case 'alphanumeric':
    case 'alphanum':
      $generator->setFormat(\Magento\SalesRule\HelperCoupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC);
      break;
    case 'alphabetical':
    case 'alpha':
      $generator->setFormat(\Magento\SalesRule\HelperCoupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHABETICAL);
      break;
    case 'numeric':
    case 'num':
      $generator->setFormat(\Magento\SalesRule\HelperCoupon::COUPON_FORMAT_NUMERIC );
      break;
  }
}

$generator->setLength(!empty($parameters['length'])? (int) $parameters['length'] : 6);
$generator->setPrefix(!empty($parameters['prefix'])? $parameters['prefix'] : '');
$generator->setSuffix(!empty($parameters['suffix'])? $parameters['suffix'] : '');

// Set the generator, and coupon type so it's able to generate
$couponManagement->generate($generator);
```

Comment: Works, also had to do "setQuantity()" & "setDelimiterAtEvery()"
Also "setFormat('alphanum')"

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to generate random code only.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$couponGenerator = $objectManager->get('\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Codegenerator'); // magnento coupon code generator

$couponHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\SalesRule\Helper\Coupon'); //coupon code helper to ger format
$couponGenerator->setFormat($couponHelper::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC); // set format or random code

$couponGenerator->setLength(8); // length of coupon code upto 32
echo $couponCode = $couponGenerator->generateCode(); //generate code

Output - zO544NsV
```